# java.text.parseException: Unparseable date : 2020-02-06T08:00:00

Tags: android, time, format, simpledateformat, parseexception

Getting parse exception when I'm applying a particular format to the date.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
try {
    String s=timeSlotsArrayList.get(position).getScheduledStartTime();
    Date d = df.parse(s);
    times.setText(df.format(d));
}
catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**AM is getting instead of PM issue image**

[image: AM is getting instead of PM issue image]

Comment: How did you format `df`?

Comment: Updated the code @Md.Asaduzzaman

Comment: Are those two different issues? How can you get any AM or PM in the image when you get a parse exception first?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Does this answer your (first) question? [Converting String to Date using SimpleDateFormat is returning random date \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50513135/converting-string-to-date-using-simpledateformat-is-returning-random-date). Maybe in conjunction with this? [Date format conversion Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896635/date-format-conversion-android).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this date format? 2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405087/what-is-this-date-format-2011-08-12t201746-384z)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't apply correct format to your `SimpleDateFormat`. Use

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

And then parse time like below:

```
Date d = df.parse(s);

String time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(d);
times.setText(time);
```

Comment: I need only time from the string,No need date

Comment: Worked but 12:30 is getting AM instead of PM.
I added image below of my code.

Comment: Use `HH:mm:ss` instead of `hh:mm:ss` for 24 hour format

Comment: I got another issue related to the date. I want to reduce one day for particular date. But It's reducing for 1 month.



df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY");
Date prevDate = df.parse(dateText.getText().toString());
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    c.setTime(prevDate);
                    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
                    Date d=c.getTime();
                    dateText.setText(df.format(d));